# How can I make my DIVs appear below each other using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following:
[image: Pic 1]
And I want these result:
[image: Pic 2]

I am using bootsrap 3

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
.product-item {
    /*height: 425px;*/
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    /*margin: 0 -10px;*/
    display: inline-block;
}
.product-item_inner {
    background-color: yellow;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    /*min-height: 522px;*/
    padding: 10px;

    width:auto; height:auto;
}
a.s_thumb img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*max-width: 270px;*/
}
div.product-item h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Google Fonts !! -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Already inserted !! -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-item">
            <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
                <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                    <img width="280" height="140" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/140/" class="img-responsive"
                         alt="title example">
                </a>
                <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 1</a>
                </h3>

                <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>


            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-item">
            <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
                <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                    <img width="280" height="240" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/240/" class="img-responsive"
                         alt="title example">
                </a>
                <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 2</a>
                </h3>

                <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-item">
            <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
                <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                    <img width="280" height="70" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/70/" class="img-responsive"
                         alt="title example">
                </a>
                <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 3</a>
                </h3>

                <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-item">
            <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
                <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                    <img width="280" height="140" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/140/" class="img-responsive"
                         alt="title example">
                </a>
                <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 4</a>
                </h3>

                <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-item">
            <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
                <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                    <img width="280" height="150" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/150/" class="img-responsive"
                         alt="title example">
                </a>
                <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 5</a>
                </h3>

                <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-item">
            <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
                <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                    <img width="280" height="205" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/205/" class="img-responsive"
                         alt="title example">
                </a>
                <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 6</a>
                </h3>

                <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>


</div>


<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bootstrap 4 has a really cool solution for this, http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of CSS3 columns.

To do that get rid of all those `col-xx` `div`s and assign the `product-item` class to the `row` `div`.

Then all that remains would be to add this style to your `product-item`:

```
.product-item { -webkit-column-count: 3; column-count: 3; }
```

**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/o8mksrc2/1/

**Demo Snippet**:

```css
.product-item { -webkit-column-count: 3; column-count: 3; }
.product-item_inner {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 10px;
    width:auto; height:auto;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
a.s_thumb img { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
div.product-item h3 { font-size: 15px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row product-item">
        <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
            <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                <img width="280" height="140" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/140/" 
                     class="img-responsive" alt="title example" />
            </a>
            <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 1</a></h3>
            <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>
        </div>        
        <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
            <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                <img width="280" height="240" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/240/" 
                     class="img-responsive" alt="title example" />
            </a>
            <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 2</a> </h3>
            <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>
        </div>
        <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
            <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                <img width="280" height="70" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/70/" 
                     class="img-responsive" alt="title example" />
            </a>
            <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 3</a></h3>
            <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>
        </div>        
        <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
            <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                <img width="280" height="140" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/140/" 
                     class="img-responsive" alt="title example" />
            </a>
            <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 4</a></h3>
            <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>
        </div>        
        <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
            <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                <img width="280" height="150" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/150/" 
                     class="img-responsive" alt="title example" />
            </a>
            <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 5</a></h3>
            <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>
        </div>        
        <div class="product-item_inner text-center">
            <a class="s_thumb" href="#">
                <img width="280" height="205" src="http://lorempixel.com/280/205/" 
                     class="img-responsive" alt="title example" />
            </a>
            <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 6</a></h3>
            <p class="s_price">250,00 € </p>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use bootstrap because it have to be responsive

Comment: @Bizboss: This ***is*** using Bootstrap. And for responsiveness, just add your media breakpoints. For example - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/o8mksrc2/2/ Try resizing the fiddle pane to see that it collpases to 2 columns on small widths and 1 column on extra small widths.

Answer (score 0):

Abhitalks was quicker for responding. For responsiveness simply add the `Media Queries` bootstrap uses in your css:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
    .product-item { -webkit-column-count: 1; column-count: 1; }
}
```

See the values here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

Already asked (by me) in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098066/grid-of-links-responsive-and-stacked). That time a user suggested **[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)** that is a jQuery plugin that return your desired behaviour and **it's completely responsive**.

With this plugin, element are *absolute positioned* in the container, based on their size, and this position is dinamically re-calculated if browser window is resized, to remain completely responsive not only on page load but also on window resize.

CSS only solution based on "*columns*" could be a perfect and light solution, but you must remember that they are [compatible only since IE10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) and above.

In addition, **with Masonry, various elements are sort by rows from left to right**, in a very similar way of a simple BootStrap grid, while **with CSS columns, all items first fill the first column, then the second and so on...** so their sort criteria on page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 product-item" style="float: left;">
```